# three.js SphereBufferedGeometry without triangulated mesh

Tags: three.js

I have been searching the google for this question, but I didn't find much.

Basically, I just want a sphere that has quads -- i.e. no triangulation in the mesh. In fact, if it is possible, I would like it to only have vertical lines, but I assume this is out of the question, but I definitely do not want diagonals.

I saw the `EdgesHelper`, but I don't *think* that is what I want regarding the creation of a sphere.

I don't think this is a duplicate, but if it is, please point me to the right place; thanks.

Comment: You can write logic to draw lines however you want. Count the segments and draw ngons of the same radius.

Comment: @pailhead I was hoping to avoid that, but after muddling around with spheres and arcs, and getting close but not quite close enough, I think I am going to have to do this -- and when I do, I can construct the wireframe it however I want. Thanks. When I get home, I'll make a little js fiddle and post it if I get it working.

Comment: Keep in mind that [WebGL doesn't support the QUAD primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503600/what-are-webgls-draw-primitives), and so "quads" are actually drawn as two co-planar triangles. This is why the edges helper can't help but draw the diagonals.

Comment: @TheJim01 that's not an entirely correct statement.

Comment: Oops hit enter way too quick. That is not why edges helper cant draw what he needs. It is incorrect because you would be using gl.lines or gl.linestrip anyway regardless of what you are drawing. Could be one segment, could be 3 around a triangle, or N around an Ngon ( that gets drawn by N-2 triangles. The reason why this doesn't work is because three.js does not support anything other than triangles.

Comment: Cool; thanks, guys|gals. fyi, I ended up finishing the project! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
I've made such customizable solution from the scratch, using `THREE.CircleGeometry()` (not buffered, though):

```
function createSphereOfQuadsWireframe(radius, widthSegments, heightSegments, color, showWidthSegments, showHeightSegments) {
  var sphereObj = new THREE.Group();

  if (showWidthSegments) {
    // width segments
    var arcGeom = createArc(radius, heightSegments, false); // as the amount of width segments may be odd, it's better to use half-circles, that's why the third parameter is `false`
    var widthSector = Math.PI * 2 / widthSegments;
    for (var ws = 0; ws < widthSegments; ws++) {
      var arcGeomTmp = arcGeom.clone();
      arcGeomTmp.rotateY(widthSector * ws);
      var arcLine = new THREE.Line(arcGeomTmp, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: color
      }));
      sphereObj.add(arcLine);
    }
  }

  if (showHeightSegments) {
    //height segments
    var heightSector = Math.PI / heightSegments;
    for (var hs = 1; hs < heightSegments; hs++) {
      var hRadius = Math.sin(hs * heightSector) * radius;
      var height = Math.cos(hs * heightSector) * radius;
      var arcHeightGeom = createArc(hRadius, widthSegments, true);
      arcHeightGeom.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);
      arcHeightGeom.translate(0, height, 0);
      var arcHeightLine = new THREE.Line(arcHeightGeom, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: color
      }));
      sphereObj.add(arcHeightLine);
    }
  }
  return sphereObj;
}

function createArc(radius, segments, full) {
  var geom = new THREE.CircleGeometry(radius, segments, Math.PI / 2, full ? Math.PI * 2 : Math.PI);
  geom.vertices.shift();
  if (full) geom.vertices.push(geom.vertices[0].clone());
  return geom;
}
```

and its use is like this:

```
var fullSphere = createSphereOfQuadsWireframe(20, 32, 16, "yellow", true, true);
scene.add(fullSphere);

var widthOnlySphere = createSphereOfQuadsWireframe(20, 32, 16, "pink", true, false);
widthOnlySphere.position.set(-50, 0, 0);
scene.add(widthOnlySphere);

var heightOnlySphere = createSphereOfQuadsWireframe(20, 32, 16, "aqua", false, true);
heightOnlySphere.position.set(50, 0, 0);
scene.add(heightOnlySphere);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/pgxunorc/) example

Comment: Just a suggestion: Renaming your dimensions from height/width into latitude/longitude may help drive home what they truly mean.

Comment: Thank you; this will surely be a big help. I am not afraid of ellipsoids as I have been working with getting my camera to move along a sphere and rotate based on mouse input, and I know my trig. I also have to "remove" 1/8 of the sphere (1/4 of the top). So, I will edit it a bit, but it's certainly nice to have this example. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TheJim01 I agree, but three.js uses widthSegments for longitude (makes sense because longitudinal lines make vertical slices with width) and heightSegments for latitude (similarly, makes sense because latitudinal lines contrive horizontal slices with depth). `tl;dr`: longitude = vertical slices with *width*; latitude = horizontal slices with *height* **+** three.js does it like prisoner849

Comment: @TheJim01 yes, I took the same names of parameters as they use, for example, in `THREE.SphereGeometry()`

Comment: Turns out I did need the quad. sphere, and thanks to you, I successfully completed my project!! I ended up using a very similar rendition of your code, but I have updated it to allow for phi- and theta- start and length. I cannot, unfortunately, create a snippet at work, but I will post it later and notify you via comment. Perhaps it would be of interest to you. Nonetheless, I cannot thank you enough, as you saved me so much time. I never would have thought to shift the vertices or do a few other things. You're a life-saver!

Comment: I have posted my js-fiddle in answer, or see [my js-fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dylnmc/3o9gae9r/). Maybe it will be useful to you.

Comment: You're welcome ) Your question was interesting for me to solve )

Answer (score 2):

see https://jsfiddle.net/dylnmc/3o9gae9r/ to see how I ended up creating my own quad. sphere that has phi- and theta- start and length values so that you can create partial spheres. Kudos to prisoner849, who answered above/below.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(-30, 60, -120);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var r = 20,
    verticalLines = 32, /* must be divisible by 4! */
    horizontalLines = 16; /* must be divisible by 2! */

var quadSphere_threeQuarters = createQuadSphere(r, 3 * verticalLines / 4, horizontalLines, {
    color: 0x0000ff
}, 0, 3 * Math.PI / 2);
scene.add(quadSphere_threeQuarters);

var quadSphere_oneEighth = createQuadSphere(r, verticalLines / 4, horizontalLines / 2, {
    color: 0xff0000
}, 3 * Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2);
quadSphere_oneEighth.position.x += 50;
scene.add(quadSphere_oneEighth);

var quadSphere_threeQuarters_right = createQuadSphere(r, 3 * verticalLines / 4, horizontalLines, {
    color: 0xff00ff
}, 0, 3 * Math.PI / 2);
quadSphere_threeQuarters_right.position.x -= 50;
scene.add(quadSphere_threeQuarters_right);

var quadSphere_oneEighth_right = createQuadSphere(r, verticalLines / 4, horizontalLines / 2, {
    color: 0xff00ff
}, 3 * Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2);
quadSphere_oneEighth_right.position.x -= 50;
scene.add(quadSphere_oneEighth_right);



function createQuadSphere(r, widthSegments, heightSegments, atts, phiStart, phiLen, thetaStart, thetaLen) {
    var sphere = new THREE.Group(),
        material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial(atts);

    if (phiStart === undefined) {
        phiStart = Math.PI / 2;
    }
    if (phiLen === undefined) {
        phiLen = 2 * Math.PI;
    }
    if (thetaStart === undefined) {
        thetaStart = 0;
    }
    if (thetaLen === undefined) {
        thetaLen = Math.PI;
    }

    /* width segments (longitude) */
    for (var phiDelta = phiLen / widthSegments, phi = phiStart, arc = createVerticalArc(r, heightSegments, thetaStart + Math.PI / 2, thetaLen); phi <= phiStart + phiLen + phiDelta; phi += phiDelta) {
        var arcTmpGeometry = arc.clone();
        arcTmpGeometry.rotateY(phi);
        var arcLine = new THREE.Line(arcTmpGeometry, material);
        sphere.add(arcLine);
    }

    /* height segments (latitude) */
    for (var thetaDelta = thetaLen / heightSegments, theta = thetaStart; theta < thetaStart + thetaLen - thetaDelta; theta += thetaDelta) {
        if (theta === 0) {
            continue;
        }
        var arcR = r * Math.sin(theta),
            arcH = r * Math.cos(theta),
            arcTmpGeometry = createHorizontalArc(arcR, widthSegments, phiStart, phiLen);
        arcTmpGeometry.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);
        arcTmpGeometry.rotateY(Math.PI / 2);
        arcTmpGeometry.translate(0, arcH, 0);
        var arcLine = new THREE.Line(arcTmpGeometry, material);
        sphere.add(arcLine);
    }

    return sphere;
}

function createVerticalArc(r, segments, thetaStart, thetaLen) {
    var geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(r, segments, thetaStart, thetaLen);
    geometry.vertices.shift();
    return geometry;
}

function createHorizontalArc(r, segments, phiStart, phiLen) {
    var geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(r, segments, phiStart, phiLen);
    geometry.vertices.shift();
    if (phiLen >= 2 * Math.PI) {
        geometry.vertices.push(geometry.vertices[0].clone());
    }
    return geometry;
}


render();

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

code:

```
function createQuadSphere(r, widthSegments, heightSegments, atts, phiStart, phiLen, thetaStart, thetaLen) {
    var sphere = new THREE.Group(),
        material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial(atts);

    if (phiStart === undefined) {
        phiStart = Math.PI / 2;
    }
    if (phiLen === undefined) {
        phiLen = 2 * Math.PI;
    }
    if (thetaStart === undefined) {
        thetaStart = 0;
    }
    if (thetaLen === undefined) {
        thetaLen = Math.PI;
    }

    /* width segments (longitude) */
    for (var phiDelta = phiLen / widthSegments, phi = phiStart, arc = createVerticalArc(r, heightSegments, thetaStart + Math.PI / 2, thetaLen); phi <= phiStart + phiLen + phiDelta; phi += phiDelta) {
        var arcTmpGeometry = arc.clone();
        arcTmpGeometry.rotateY(phi);
        var arcLine = new THREE.Line(arcTmpGeometry, material);
        sphere.add(arcLine);
    }

    /* height segments (latitude) */
    for (var thetaDelta = thetaLen / heightSegments, theta = thetaStart; theta < thetaStart + thetaLen - thetaDelta; theta += thetaDelta) {
        if (theta === 0) {
            continue;
        }
        var arcR = r * Math.sin(theta),
            arcH = r * Math.cos(theta),
            arcTmpGeometry = createHorizontalArc(arcR, widthSegments, phiStart, phiLen);
        arcTmpGeometry.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);
        arcTmpGeometry.rotateY(Math.PI / 2);
        arcTmpGeometry.translate(0, arcH, 0);
        var arcLine = new THREE.Line(arcTmpGeometry, material);
        sphere.add(arcLine);
    }

    return sphere;
}

function createVerticalArc(r, segments, thetaStart, thetaLen) {
    var geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(r, segments, thetaStart, thetaLen);
    geometry.vertices.shift();
    return geometry;
}

function createHorizontalArc(r, segments, phiStart, phiLen) {
    var geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(r, segments, phiStart, phiLen);
    geometry.vertices.shift();
    if (phiLen >= 2 * Math.PI) {
        geometry.vertices.push(geometry.vertices[0].clone());
    }
    return geometry;
}
```

how to use:

```
var radius = 20, widthSegments = 32, heightSegments = 16,
    atts = {color: "red"},
    phiStart = Math.PI / 2, phiLen = Math.PI,
    thetaStart = 0, thetaLen = Math.PI;
var sphere = createQuadSphere(radius, widthSegments / 2,
             heightSegments, atts, phiStart, phiLen,
             thetaStart, thetaLen);
scene.add(sphere);
```

---

I think the sphere might be rotated 180 in x-z plane (phi), but I am tired from long day at work, and it suites my needs :)

---

terrible place to put this, but I also made arcs with thickness .. because I had to for my project: https://jsfiddle.net/u98wssL2/

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(-80, 80, -350);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.domElement.style.backgroundColor = "#bbbbbb"
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var r = 20,
    verticalLines = 32,
    /* must be divisible by 4! */
    horizontalLines = 32; /* must be divisible by 2! */

var tubeArc = createTubeArc(50, horizontalLines, 5, 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI, 'round', {
    'color': 'red'
})
scene.add(tubeArc);

var tubeArc1 = createTubeArc(50, horizontalLines, 5, 8, Math.PI, Math.PI, 'round', {
    'color': 'yellow'
})
tubeArc1.position.x += 50;
scene.add(tubeArc1);

var tubeArc2 = createTubeArc(50, horizontalLines, 5, 8, 0, Math.PI, 'round', {
    'color': 'blue'
})
tubeArc2.position.x -= 50;
scene.add(tubeArc2);

function createTubeArc(radius, segments, cylinderRadius, cylinderSegments, thetaStart, thetaLen, capStyle, atts) {
    var tubeArc = new THREE.Group();
    if (capStyle !== "round" && capStyle !== "open" && capStyle !== "flat") {
        capStyle = "round";
    }
    // TODO: implement round :D (when you think you might need something ...)
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(atts);
    for (var thetaDelta = thetaLen / segments, theta = thetaStart + thetaDelta / 2, cylinderHeight = Math.sqrt(2 * radius * radius - 2 * radius * radius * Math.cos(thetaDelta)) + Math.sqrt(2 * cylinderRadius * cylinderRadius - 2 * cylinderRadius * cylinderRadius * Math.cos(thetaDelta)); theta < thetaStart + thetaLen + thetaDelta / 2; theta += thetaDelta) {
        var ptX = radius * Math.cos(theta),
            ptY = radius * Math.sin(theta),
            cylinderTmpGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(cylinderRadius, cylinderRadius, cylinderHeight, cylinderSegments, 1, (capStyle === "open"), 0, 2 * Math.PI),
            cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(cylinderTmpGeometry, material);
        cylinder.rotateZ(theta);
        cylinder.position.x = ptX;
        cylinder.position.y = ptY;
        if (capStyle === "open") {
            cylinder.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        }
        tubeArc.add(cylinder);
    }

    return tubeArc;
}


render();

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```